# Linux ubuntu 17.04. Трабла с grub 2

Tags: linux

Такая проблемка случилась. Полетел grub после обновления винды. И крч пытался его восстановить, но никакие методы просто не получаются. Решил перебить убунту, но при переустановке, выдает ошибку точно не помню но вроде как то так "sudo grub-install /dev/sda5 невозможно" и что ошибка неисправима. И после этого запускается граб при включении, но он не тот. То есть там есть терминал выглядит он так и я как бы пытался ввести многое, что находил в нете, но пишет что нету таких команд...

Comment: И в чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: В чем проблема? И как переустановить или точнее установить grub?